# SOCKS5 proxy to tunnel TCP with additional headers and TLS

Tags: ssl, tcp, proxy, reverse-proxy, socks5

Is it possible to create a local SOCKS proxy for an application that tunnels TCP traffic with additional PPv2 headers and establishes TLS? The end server is another TCP proxy that should parse PPV2 headers without decrypting.